# Projected gradient reach minimizer when $\textbf x_{t+1} = \textbf x_{t}$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

Suppose that a closed subset $X \subseteq \mathbb R^d$ is convex, and we have the following projected gradient descent algorithm:
$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{\arg\!\max}
\begin{cases} 
\textbf y_{t+1} := \textbf x_t - \gamma\nabla f(\textbf t) \\
\textbf x_{t+1} := \Pi_X(\textbf y_{t+1}) = \argmin\limits_{\textbf x \in X} \|\textbf x - \textbf y_{t+1}\|
\end{cases}$

(with $\textbf x_t \in X, \forall\ t$ and $\gamma>0$)

For an iteration $t$, $\textbf x_{t+1} = \textbf x_t$. I need to prove that $\textbf  x_t$ is a minimizer of $f$ over $X$.

**My attempt so far**: since $$\textbf x_{t+1} = \textbf x_t = \argmin\limits_{\textbf x \in X} \|\textbf x - \textbf x_t + \gamma\nabla f(\textbf x_t)\|$$
We have for all $\textbf x \in X$ $$\|\textbf x - \textbf x_t + \gamma\nabla f(\textbf x_t)\|^2 \geq \|\textbf x_t - \textbf x_t + \gamma\nabla f(\textbf x_t)\|^2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \|\textbf x - \textbf x_t + \gamma\nabla f(\textbf x_t)\|^2 \geq \|\gamma\nabla f(\textbf x_t)\|^2$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \|\textbf x - \textbf x_t \|^2 + 2\gamma\nabla f(\textbf x_t)^\top (\textbf x - \textbf x_t) \geq 0$$
I'm aware of the theorem (*) that $\textbf x_t$ is a minimizer of $f$ over $X$ is equivalent to $\nabla f(\textbf x_t)^\top (\textbf x - \textbf x_t) \geq 0$, but there is an additional term here.

Any suggestions on how can I proceed from here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I have overcomplicated my thinking process. There is a useful fact stated in the same document I read: If $X \subseteq \mathbb R^d$ is closed and convex, $\textbf x \in X, \textbf y \in \mathbb R^d$, then
$$(\textbf x - \Pi_X (\textbf y))^\top(\textbf y - \Pi_X (\textbf y)) \leq 0 \quad \text{(**)}$$
This is the result of applying theorem (*) to the function $d_{\textbf y}(\textbf x) = \|\textbf x - \textbf y\|^2$ over $X$ with minimizer $\Pi_X (\textbf y)$

Replace $\textbf y = \textbf y_{t+1} = \textbf x_t - \gamma\nabla f(\textbf x_t)$ back into (**) and do some equivalent transformation will give you $\nabla f(\textbf x_t)^\top (\textbf x - \textbf x_t) \geq 0$, which is literally (*) again